# Remove "File, edit,...etc" menus from Eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I want to remove the File, edit, Source, Refactor, etc. menus from my RCP application
Can I use `hideActionSet()` ? or what should I do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's right; in your **ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor**, override **postWindowOpen()**.

The tricky bit is usually figuring out the names of the actionsets that you want to remove, but you can use the old standby ALT-SHIFT-F2 (the default keybinding for 'Plugin-in Menu Spy') and click on one of the menu items that you want to remove.

*Note that if the menu item is disabled, the spy won't give you any info on it.*

```
public void postWindowOpen() {
    runApplicationWorkbenchDelegate();

    // remove unwanted UI contributions that eclipse makes by default
    IWorkbenchWindow[] windows = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows();

    for (int i = 0; i < windows.length; ++i) {
        IWorkbenchPage page = windows[i].getActivePage();
        if (page != null) {
            // hide generic 'File' commands
            page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.openFiles");

            // hide 'Convert Line Delimiters To...'
            page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.convertLineDelimitersTo");

            // hide 'Search' commands
            page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.search.searchActionSet");

            // hide 'Annotation' commands
            page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.annotationNavigation");

            // hide 'Forward/Back' type navigation commands
            page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.navigation");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to remove the entire Refactor menu itself in my RCP application. How to do that? Alt+Shift+F2 shows id only for actions in refactor!

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is old:

[Lars Vogel's tutorial about Eclipse Activities](http://blog.vogella.com/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/) shows how to hide entire menus in an RCP application rather than removing single menu-entries.

EDIT:
Alternatively you can use the MenuManager attached to the workbench window to show or hide Menus/Contributions. 
Try the following code to hide all menus:

```
WorkbenchWindow workbenchWin = (WorkbenchWindow)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
MenuManager menuManager = workbenchWin.getMenuManager();
IContributionItem[] items = menuManager.getItems();

for(IContributionItem item : items) {
  item.setVisible(false);
}
```