# How to remove unwanted menu contributions in eclipse rcp application?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have made a eclipse RCP application, everything is working fine but i recently noticed the Refractor option in menu. I would like to get rid of it. I have the following in ActionBarAdvisor.java:

```
@Override
    protected void fillMenuBar(IMenuManager menu) {

        menu.add(createFile());
        menu.add(createEdit());
        menu.add(createNavigate());
        menu.add(createProject());
        menu.add(new GroupMarker(IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS));
        menu.add(createWindow());
        menu.add(createHelp());

    }
```

The above functions add actions to menu as:

```
edit.add(undoAct);
```

and also undoAct is defined as:

```
private IWorkbenchAction undoAction
```

makeActions function has contents as:

```
@Override
    protected void makeActions(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
        undoAction = ActionFactory.UNDO.create(window);
        undoAction.setText("Undo Menu");
        register(undoAction);
}
```

I found a suggestion which said to use hideActionSets to hide the menu. But I could not hide the entire menu but just its actions!
[Remove "File, edit,...etc" menus from Eclipse RCP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774138/remove-file-edit-etc-menus-from-eclipse-rcp-application)

How to remove Refractor option now? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use activities, as described [here](http://codeandme.blogspot.ru/2011/09/hiding-ui-elements-in-rcp.html). 
First, you will need to [find the ID of the menu](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/ide4edu-dev/msg00155.html):

> 1. Use the Plug-In Spy
>
> The first way is to use the Plug-In Spy. Press alt-shift-F2 and click on a
>   menu item or toolbar button that you want to be hidden. If there is an ID
>   string under the heading "active action definition identifier" then you are
>   in luck. This item has been added using the Command Extension and you can
>   use this ID as the pattern argument for the Activities Extension. But not
>   all items that have been added using the Command Extension present their ID
>   string to the plug-in spy.
>
> As a side note, the ID strings are period separated. For instance the ID for
>   a button might be "org.eclipse.ui.navigate.backwardHistory". Regular
>   expressions use the period to stand for any character. Luckily the period
>   used as a wild card matches with actual period characters so you don't need
>   to escape them if you don't want to. I find it makes it a bit easier to read
>   if they are not escaped and it is highly unlikely it will cause any
>   ambiguous matches.
>
> 2. Use the Plug-In Registry and plugin.xml files
>
> The second way is to use the Plug-In Registry. You can open this view by
>   going to:
>
> Window/Show View.../Other/Plug-in Development/Plug-In Registry
>
> What you would like to do is to try to get a couple pieces of information:
>
> a) the plugin that is contributing the UI element
>   b) information about what kind of extension the plugin is using to create
>   the UI element
>
> If there is a very unique word associated with the UI element or its tool
>   tip then you can use this in the Plug-In Registry's filter field to try to
>   nail down which plug-in is contributing the UI element. The filter field is
>   not a very powerful tool so it can be a bit frustrating to use. It does not
>   allow wildcards and does not match space characters.
>
> When you track down which plug-in is contributing the UI element then you
>   open the the plug-in in question from the Plug-Ins view which is found
>   grouped with the Package Explorer in the Plug-in Development perspective.
>   Then go to the Extensions tab and search for the ID string which can usually
>   be found in either a usage of the Command or ActionSet extension. If the UI
>   element is added using an ActionSet then you prefix the plug-in ID to UI ID
>   in the pattern argument given to the Activities Extension. For example
>   org.eclipse.ui.actionsets.foo becomes the pattern
>   org.eclipse.ui/org.eclipse.ui.actionsets.foo.

Then create a new `Activity` which will never be activated and a corresponding `activityPatternBinding` with the `id` you found in the last step. It will look like this in your `plugin.xml`:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">  
   <activity id="myActivity" name="MenuHidingActivity">  
      <enabledWhen>  
         <with variable="activePartId">    
            <equals value="nonExistentPartId"></equals>      
         </with>
      </enabledWhen>
   </activity>
   <activityPatternBinding activityId="myActivity" pattern="menuItemID">  
   </activityPatternBinding>
</extension>
```

Comment: menuItemID is the ID of the menu i want to hide? and what are activePartId and nonExistentPartId. Also I found Refactor is added by org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring and in that under commands extensions the id for the corresponding category is: org.eclipse.ltk.ui.category.refactoring
SO what is the contents?

Comment: "menuItemID is the ID of the menu i want to hide?" Yes. This doesn't have to be the same as ID of command category, look under "org.eclipse.ui.menus" extension. activePartId is the name of the variable, it stays as-is. nonExistentPartId is some part ID which doesn't exist. You can also replace tag under <enabledWhen> with any other expression which is always false (e.g. "count of something is -1")